# Dos columnas con el mismo nombre

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo un problema con la consulta que estoy realizando, al unir dos tablas con un join no me aparece una columna debido a que tienen el mismo nombre otra. Traté de usar un select como lo hago normalmente en sql pero no sigue sin aparecer.

```
$user = DB::table('app_registro_usuario')
        ->join('app_alumno_curso', 'app_alumno_curso.id_alumno', '=', 'app_registro_usuario.id')
        ->join('app_curso', 'app_alumno_curso.id_curso', '=', 'app_curso.id')
        ->join('app_sexo', 'app_registro_usuario.id_sexo', '=', 'app_sexo.id')
        ->where('id_tipo_usuario', 1)
        ->where('app_registro_usuario.id', $id)
        ->where('id_estalecimiento', $id_establecimiento)
        ->first();
```

El nombre de la columna que se encuentra en dos tablas que conecto es "nombre".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la palabra `as` dentro del `select()` para asignar alias a las columnas o bien utilizar un `selectRaw()`

Ejemplos

Con `select()`

```
$user = DB::table('app_registro_usuario')

 ->select('app_curso.nombre as nombre_curso', 'app_registro_usuario.nombre as nombre_usu')

        ->join('app_alumno_curso', 'app_alumno_curso.id_alumno', '=', 'app_registro_usuario.id')
        ->join('app_curso', 'app_alumno_curso.id_curso', '=', 'app_curso.id')
        ->join('app_sexo', 'app_registro_usuario.id_sexo', '=', 'app_sexo.id')
        ->where('id_tipo_usuario', 1)
        ->where('app_registro_usuario.id', $id)
        ->where('id_estalecimiento', $id_establecimiento)
        ->first();
```

Con `selectRaw()`

```
$user = DB::table('app_registro_usuario')

->selectRaw('app_curso.nombre nombre_curso, app_registro_usuario.nombre nombre_usu')

        ->join('app_alumno_curso', 'app_alumno_curso.id_alumno', '=', 'app_registro_usuario.id')
        ->join('app_curso', 'app_alumno_curso.id_curso', '=', 'app_curso.id')
        ->join('app_sexo', 'app_registro_usuario.id_sexo', '=', 'app_sexo.id')
        ->where('id_tipo_usuario', 1)
        ->where('app_registro_usuario.id', $id)
        ->where('id_estalecimiento', $id_establecimiento)
        ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes asignar un alias aparte de diferenciarlos con el nombre de la tabla de cada campo correspondiente, todo esto lo haces en el select:

```
->select('tabla1.nombre as nombre1', 'tabla2.nombre as nombre2')
```